# Unable to click on "DRIVE" element present under 'ul' and 'li'

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click an element with id "DRIVE", but unable to do so.

I have use xpath like:

1.driver.findElement(By.id("DRIVE")).click();
                      or
2.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#DRIVE")).click();

Here is code:

```
<ul class="js-tablist ultabs tabs__list" role="tablist">
<li class="js-tablist__item tabs__item" role="presentation">
<a id="A_DOMICILIO" class="js-tablist__link active tabs__link" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-delivery" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">
Entregar en...</a>
</li>
<li class="js-tablist__item tabs__item" role="presentation">
<a id="DRIVE" class="js-tablist__link tabs__link" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-collect" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false">
Recoger en...</a>
</li>
<p class="title-04">
Dirección</p></ul>
```

I am not able to click on "DRIVE" element.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to...". Do you get any error? Or do you expect some kind of event that is not happening? How do you decide you are not able to click on it?

Comment: I am not getting any error neither element is clicked.